# How to send Zcash (ZEC) using WIF?

Tags: python, node.js, zcash

Actually I'm not founding any way to import the WIF Key on any zcash wallet to send zcash.

The only way I've found is guarda wallet that can import wif but the error is that the app got stuck on "Calculate network fee" and can't send zcash (ZEC).

Someone knows any other way to send zcash using WIF key?

Can be any way including programming code in nodejs or python or something like this.

Thanks